# Instagram Login without oAuth

Tags: c#, android, networking, instagram

I am trying again to login to instagram, but i have to do this without using their api v2 which uses oAuth for verifying.
The only thing i have is Username and Password to login.
So what i did was looked for the way, instagram application for Android and hopefully IOS does that.

I see that it creates a request at the following url:
   https://instagr.am/api/v1/accounts/login/

If you would visit that link directly, you will more likely get a error saying that the page couldn't be find. After a little bit of googling, i came across a 2 years old post which states that in the Useragent, we have to contain the string "Instagram" for it to work.

I did that by faking the useragent and the result is as follows:

```
{"status":"fail","message":"Your version of Instagram is out of date. Please upgrade your app in the Play Store to log in to Instagram."}
```

Now, i am guessing that we also need to add something else or some other headers too, so i was looking for a way to grab the request being sended to instagram by either of their Android or IOS app.

So next i downloaded Bluestack and installed and ran instagram on my computer using this. I was able to install and login it successfully, but then i was unable to log it using Charles since the request is being sent to https:// server

I also tried to grab it through Wireshark but unfortuantely, i am not much experienced in using it and hence don't know it purpose.

**So could anyone help me to get how to login to instagram with C# without using oAuth, cuz i just have username and password.**

**I would probably code the end part of requesting myself, but i am unable to capture the headers being sent to instagram.**

Also, if there is anything like Charles/Wireshark which captures network traffic for Android, do let me know about it too.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to capture the request and see the request headers using Fiddler if you can tell your device to use your pcs internet connection by going through USB. It seems your getting close but might just need a version number somewhere in your request.

Comment: I already tried using fiddler. But its a proxy and will only capture the requests that are sent to the specified port. If you set the proxy to nothing, then fiddler won't be able to capture that request. I am looking for something like Wireshark which captures at network level, but sigh, i don't know its use :( + its ssl so encrypted too in wireshark

Answer (score 1):

Yeah you can do this using `Webview` 
Here you go

```
 mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                UrlQuerySanitizer.ValueSanitizer sanitizer = UrlQuerySanitizer.getAllButNulLegal();
// remember to decide if you want the first or last parameter with the same name
// If you want the first call setPreferFirstRepeatedParameter(true);
                sanitizer.sanitize(url);
                String value = sanitizer.sanitize("username"); // get your value
                if(MyBridge.getUsername()!=null)username = MyBridge.getUsername();
               return  true;

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
//                showLoading();

                CookieManager.getInstance().removeAllCookies(null);
//                CookieManager.getInstance().flush();
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if (url.equalsIgnoreCase(mURL)) {
                    view.addJavascriptInterface(new MyBridge(InstagramOfficalLoginActivity.this), "bridge");
                    String javascript = "javascript: document.getElementsByClassName(\"_0mzm- sqdOP  L3NKy       \")[0].onclick = function() {\n" +
                            "        var username = document.getElementsByName(\"username\").value;\n" +
                            "        var password = document.getElementsByName(\"password\").value;\n" +
                            "        bridge.saveData(username, password);\n" +
                            "    };";
                    view.loadUrl(javascript);
                }


                    if (isSessionid ) {
//                        username = MyBridge.getUsername();
                        //сохранение данных пользователя
                        Logins logins = new Logins();
                        logins.setUserId(InstaUtils.getUserId());
                        logins.setUserName("");
                        logins.setProfilePic("");
                        logins.setSession_id(InstaUtils.getSessionid());
                        logins.setCooki(InstaUtils.getCookies());
                        logins.setCsrf(InstaUtils.getCsrf());

                        long id = DataObjectRepositry.dataObjectRepositry.addNewUser(logins);


                        PreferencesManager.savePref(GlobalConstant.USERNAME,username);
                        PreferencesManager.savePref(GlobalConstant.USER_ID, InstaUtils.getUserId());
                        PreferencesManager.savePref(GlobalConstant.TOKEN, InstaUtils.getSessionid());
                        PreferencesManager.savePref(GlobalConstant.PROFILE_PIC,"");




                        Intent intent = new Intent(InstagramOfficalLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);

                        PreferencesManager.savePref("isLogin",true);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.putExtra("user", InstaUtils.getUserId());
                        intent.putExtra("database_id",String.valueOf(id));

                        mWebView.destroy();
                        mWebView = null;
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }

            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
                super.onLoadResource(view, url);
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);

                try {
                    String session_id = getCookie(url, "sessionid");
                    String csrftoken = getCookie(url, "csrftoken");
                    String userid = getCookie(url, "ds_user_id");
                    if (session_id != null && csrftoken != null && userid != null) {
                        isSessionid = true;
                        InstaUtils.setSessionId(session_id);
                        InstaUtils.setUserId(userid);
                        InstaUtils.setCookies(cookies);
                        InstaUtils.setCsrf(csrftoken, cookies);

                    }
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                ToastUtils.ErrorToast(InstagramOfficalLoginActivity.this, description);
            }

            @TargetApi(android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            @Override
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest req, WebResourceError rerr) {
                // Redirect to deprecated method, so you can use it in all SDK versions
                onReceivedError(view, rerr.getErrorCode(), rerr.getDescription().toString(), req.getUrl().toString());
            }


        });

        mWebView.loadUrl(mURL);
```

You can also download fully working code from my github profile [Here](https://github.com/beNitinhere/Instagram-Profile-Downloader) is the link.

I hope it work,Thanks :)

Comment: Would you like to share why this app  (you gave git repo url for) was removed from playstore

Answer (score 0):

you can always login through https://instagram.com/accounts/login/ having only login\password.

having ability to sniff traffic will not help you, as they sign all their messages now to prevent things you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can find Instaguser library at here. https://github.com/ThinhVu/InstagramUser

Instaguser allow you login into instagram without OAuth.
At the moment, you can change user information: username, biography, ... etc.